# Python: return function arguments for a condition

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return

I'm new to Python and trying to automate finding optimum operating parameters of a savgol filter that feeds into PLS analysis. First, I had a prediction function calculate results and plot them.

To try and automate optimising, I have a for loop that goes over a range of numbers then feeds this number into t. I want the filter which then goes into the function. The aim is to find the smallest possible result after applying the function and return the arguments that gave rise to it.

I'm not sure how to do this. Also, I don't want the for loop to produce plot every single time. Do I just cut and paste the section of code that does this into the loop function?

```py
def loopit():
    for derivative in range(1,3):
        for windowlength in range(5, 50, 2):
            X2_calib = savgol_filter(X_calib, windowlength, polyorder = 4, deriv=derivative)
            X2_valid = savgol_filter(X_valid, windowlength, polyorder = 4, deriv=derivative)
            #invoking prediction function
            prediction(X2_calib, Y_calib, X2_valid, Y_valid, plot_components=False)
            difference = (abs((pd.DataFrame(Y_valid))-(pd.DataFrame(Y_pred))))/abs(pd.DataFrame(Y_valid))
            sumOfDifference = difference.sum()

    #minimum of all sum of prediction
    minimum = min(sumOfDifference)
    return (minimum)
```

Comment: first try then come back if you it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your problem right, you want to loop through bunch of hyper parameters and return not just the minimum that their iterations yielded but also the parameters which yielded it.

If you want your arguments i.e `derivative` & `windowlength` to be returned , just try

```
def loopit():
    results = {} 
    _min = 100.0 # Or any other value which you think will be higher than all of the minimums
    for derivative in range(1,3):
        for windowlength in range(5, 50, 2):
            .
            .
            .### Do Something
            .
            .
            .
            sumOfDifference = difference.sum()
            if min(sumOfDifference) < _min:
                results['minimum'] = min
                results['derivative_val'] = derivative
                results['windowlenghts_val'] = windowlength
                _min = min(sumOfDifference)

    return results
```

To call your function just do :

```
res = loopit()
print(res['minimum'])
print(res['derivative_val'])
print(res['windowlenghts_val'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does the underscore "_" before min mean? And why you define it after you initialise it?

Comment: underscore "_" put there is to differentiate between 'min' function of python and the variable you created, you can rename it to `min_sod` or anything, its just a variable. Declaration of variables is not required in Python, so just initialising it would do the job of telling the variable _min, that it belongs to 'float' category. `_min = min(sumOfDifference)` is just finding the minimum of the `sumOfDifference ` and assigning it to `_min ` variable. Hope it helps, please accept this answer if it solved your query.